# HTML5 Video is not loading in mobile device why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Code shown below

```
<video poster="http://mediamoments.in/images/Logo-PNG-bkg.png" id="bgvid" playsinline autoplay muted>
    <source src="http://www.mediamoments.in/vid/MM_Logo_Identity.mp4" type="video/mp4" id="bgvid1">
    </video>
```

Script

```
document.getElementById('bgvid').addEventListener('ended',myHandler,false);
function myHandler(e) {
    console.log('ended');
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById('bgvid').play();
    }, 1000);
};
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rijo/stfcf8ny/6/

Comment: Its working fine in browser but, might be slow due to the internet... I don't know

Comment: Is thr any special code for that due to the slow internet issue...? May any browser compatibility  issue ?

Comment: i've had this problem not so long ago, the only thing i now is, that only muted videos can autoplay on iOS devices: [new video policies for ios](https://webkit.org/blog/6784/new-video-policies-for-ios/)

Comment: is it a local page or a published one? and or is the video source in the same domain  as the page?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what device you want to play the video on you have might have to specify the format for it. This is due to that different browsers support different formats.

To do so add multiple format references (mp4, webm, ogg etc.).

You can use this: [**caniuse**](https://caniuse.com/#search=mp4) to see the browser support for different formats.

**Android**
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats.html

**Ios**
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/iPhoneOSTechOverview/iPhoneOSTechnologies/iPhoneOSTechnologies.html

Answer (score 0):

To cater for all devices, we usually reference the .mp4, .ogg and .webm files, each browser/device can support different formats.

Comment: i'll check it and let me know! Thanks for the reply